# Merging Latitude and Longitude from separate columns in a Dataframe then use haversine for distance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, haversine

I'm doing the New York taxi problem from Kaggle for practice. The taxi pickup and dropoff points are given as four columns in the dataframe: pickup_latitude, pickup_longitude, dropoff_latitude, dropoff_longitude. I want to make the pickup lat and long into one and the same for dropoff, so that I can use them in a haversine function to calculate distance. I'm having trouble with this whole part.

I want it in the format (lat, long) with the comma in between so I can use it directly with haversine

Comment: Hi, you seem new. Please always post what you tried!. Have a look at the apply function. Like `df.iloc[:, 'pickup'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['pickup_latitude'], x['pickup_longitude'])) `. Make sure that you post the code you have here if you have follow up questions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
df["long_lat"] = list(zip(df["pickup_longitude"], df["pickup_latitude"]))
```

Also you could use geopandas:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df["pickup_longitude"], df["pickup_latitude"])]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
geo_df = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
```